# What format is the time member of a MSG structure?

Tags: winapi, windows-messages

The windows messaging system assigns the post time as a DWORD to every message.

```
typedef struct tagMSG {
  HWND   hwnd;
  UINT   message;
  WPARAM wParam;
  LPARAM lParam;
  DWORD  time; // <---
  POINT  pt;
} MSG, *PMSG, *LPMSG;
```

But I can find no documentation indicating what that DWORD represents. Is it seconds, milliseconds, nanoseconds? From what point in history is it counting?

Comment: While it may be useful to know what unit the `time` member represents (milliseconds), I fail to see a good reason to ask about its base. The only useful information you can extract from it is a time *interval*. If you're asking for its base, you're likely going in the wrong direction.

Comment: Without knowing what the base represents it's impossible to convert `time` to a standard format and it's impossible to compare it to time stamps of other formats. You can't even determine the interval between when a message posted and when it was retrieved from the queue without knowing the base.

Comment: Well, true, diagnostics (and possibly runtime tuning) would warrant knowing `time`'s absolute base. I assume that transforming between different display formats is just an artifact of logging/presenting the diagnostic information.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found it.

GetMessageTime defines it as the number of milliseconds since the system was started.

Comment: That was exactly, what I wanted to post as link, but You have been faster.

Comment: That information is posted as a comment at the bottom of the [`MSG` documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644958.aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: See also `GetTickCount`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I know. I'm the one that posted it.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: I don't see any comment, and apparently there hasn't been one [since April 2012](https://web.archive.org/web/20120414181315/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644958.aspx), and probably not before that either.

Comment: There _was_ a comment on that MSDN article. Microsoft must have removed it. ;-(